# HTML click button full screen

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to inject my JS code in order to click the "fullscreen" button for this html video - http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm

Problem is, I don't know the function to call full screen. What is it called?

```
function fullScreenClick() {         
  var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video');     
  video[0].play();
}  

fullScreenClick();
```

Comment: Please read [Fullscreen_API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API)? It may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's element.requestFullscreen().

```
function fullScreenClick() {         
  var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
  video.requestFullscreen();
}  

fullScreenClick();
```

To support IE and Safari, you might need to use `webkitRequestFullscreen` or `msRequestFullscreen`.

Check the document [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen.asp) or [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], not just a link?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<script>
var elem = document.getElementById("myvideo");
function openFullscreen() {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Safari */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by using the `onClick` function of the `video` element.
First, you need to wrap your video inside the video tag. I have added the code so you can better see the example:

```js
$('#video').click(function(){this.paused?this.play():this.pause();});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="video"><source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm"></video>
```

Or you can simply add the inline function into your HTML `onclick` tag.

Answer (score 0):

For that just type in `video.style.width = '100%';` and `video.style.height = '100%'`

Like this:

```
function fullScreenClick() {         
var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video');     
video[0].play();
video.style.width = '100%';
video.style.height = '100%';
}  

fullScreenClick();
```